# How to make screenshot by Selenide every time when @Then falls?

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, settings, screenshot, selenide

I use Selenide + Cucumber + IntellijIDEA and I want to get screenshot every time when `@Then` - inside only `assertEquals` - falls with `java.lang.AssertionError`.

How can I configure it? Now it makes screenshots every time when `@When` falls, but if it's `@Then` I can only see actual and expected values.

Answer (score 0):

Check [official documentation](http://selenide.org/documentation/screenshots.html) to understand how to manipulate with screenshot taking logic.

Selenide takes screenshots automatically on every test failure. And its a really good in-built feature, so I only see benefit if it gets screenshot even if you are on `Given`/`When` step cause it may help you to analyse why your test failed